# On click of a button, render all pie's of pie chart in highcharts in a different div

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm able to do it for a single pie when user clicks on the pie itself.

I do it by

1. listen click event on highchart pie
2. get the clicked object of the pie
3. convert the object to the json required and render it in the other div

I want all the pie's of the pie chart to be rendered in different div's on click of a button

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your chart options in a variable and use them to render new chart in click event:

```
var chartOptions = {
  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
  },
  series: [{
    events: {
      click: function(){
        this.chart.destroy();
        Highcharts.chart('container2', chartOptions);
      }
    },
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
      name: 'Chrome',
      y: 61.41,
      sliced: true,
      selected: true
    }, {
      name: 'Internet Explorer',
      y: 11.84
    }, {
      name: 'Firefox',
      y: 10.85
    }, {
      name: 'Edge',
      y: 4.67
    }, {
      name: 'Safari',
      y: 4.18
    }, {
      name: 'Sogou Explorer',
      y: 1.64
    }, {
      name: 'Opera',
      y: 1.6
    }, {
      name: 'QQ',
      y: 1.2
    }, {
      name: 'Other',
      y: 2.61
    }]
  }]
}

Highcharts.chart('container', chartOptions);
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sndcrtqe/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#destroy